# Doubt regarding Macaulay resultant formulation: How to proceed when the numerator and denominator matrices are singular?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I was remommended to post this querry in Engineering stackexchange, as my original post in mathoverflow was out of scope. Apologies, if thats the same here as well.
I was drawn by the method of Macaulay resultants to find the zeros of a multivariate-polynomial systems. My doubt is regarding the methodology, discussed in the paper titled ["Solutions of Multivariate Polynomial Systems using Macaulay Resultant Expressions"](https://www.academia.edu/8171808/Solutions_of_Multivariate_Polynomial_Systems_using_Macaulay_Resultant_Expressions). My query is regarding the **example of intersection of three spheres**. After substituting the centers and radii into the numerator and denominator matrices, the rank of $N_{15\times15}$ and $D_{3\times3}$ are 13 and 2 respectively, making both of them singular.
However, in the paper, under the section **construction of D**, it says that "since D is vanishing, M must be replaced with its largest non-vanishing minor". It then proceeds to do so by dropping the second, third and fourth rows and columns of the $M_{15\times15}$ matrix.

What baffles me is, since the rank of the $M_{15\times15}$ matrix is 13, shouldnt there be a non-vanishing minor of size $(13\times13)$?, as opposed to the $12\times12$ 'submatrix' in the paper?. Also, is the new matrix resulting from the dropping of the second, third and fourth rows and columns, a minor of the N matrix? Isn't it just a submatrix? Are they both different? I am eagerly awaiting the answers.